# TriggerEnter is not working for && operator in unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I have craete 2 ball sprite & one hole sprite, when this 2 ball sprite enters into the hole it need to load new scene.

im trying to find multi collision with AND operator but it's not working,if i try with one condition it workes fine, i don't know why.

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
{
    if ((col.gameObject.tag == "ball2") && (col.gameObject.tag == "ball")) {
        Application.LoadLevel("Main");
    }

}
```

Comment: `col.gameObject.tag` is a string.  Whatever value it has, it can't possibly be equal to both `"ball"` and `"ball2"` at the same time.  You need to rethink your logic.

Comment: @user12864 How can i make to detect multi collision ?

Comment: I have craete 2 ball sprite & one hole sprite, when this 2 ball sprite enters into the hole it need to load new scene.This what i'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Logistically, the code you've presented can never equate to true, because you're comparing the same string against two different values. If it returns false from the first test, it returns false. If it returns true from the first test, then it will always return false from the second, because the first evaluated it as being "ball2" - and thus it will return false.

If you're looking for it to return true if *either* (not both) side is true, use the or operator (`condition1 || condition2`)

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
{
    if ((col.gameObject.tag == "ball2")
        || (col.gameObject.tag == "ball"))
    {
        Application.LoadLevel("Main");
    }
}
```

ps, yes, I like the Visual Studio code formatting, particularly for cases where conditional blocks are multiple lines

EDIT: Going by your comments, you're waiting to get two objects into the collision. In such a case, you cannot perform this AND test, because you're testing the same object since you only received the `col` parameter once. Because you get each collision as a discreet, separate event, you should instead set a flag per occurrence, and then advance when both flags have been set.

```
private bool ball = false;
private bool ball2 = false;
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
{
    // Set each flag individually to allow for separate events triggering each
    if(col.gameObject.tag == "ball") ball = true;
    if(col.gameObject.tag == "ball2") ball2 = true;

    // Perform operation once both flags have been set
    if(ball && ball2) Application.LoadLevel("Main");
}
```

Comment: i'm checking for both side true AND operation .

Comment: I have craete 2 ball sprite & one hole sprite, when this 2 ball sprite enters into the hole it need to load new scene.This what i'm trying to do.

Comment: If you want to wait for two objects to enter a space, you'll need to test for two separate collisions, since each one will happen as a separate event. My apologies for misinterpreting the question, allow me to update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Add two different collider with two different Gameobject and add two different collider script. Access one variable from other script if that's true then go on...

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col) // Collider1 Script
{
  if ((col.gameObject.tag == "ball2"))
  {
      firstcollider = true;
  }
}


void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col) // Collider2 Script
{
 if (Collider1.firstcollider == true ) && (col.gameObject.tag == "ball"))
 {
     Application.LoadLevel("Main");
 }
}
```

Refer Google to access a variable from one script to another script if you dont know. I don't know this is the best way for code but just for crack....